# Custom collector not compile

Tags: java, lambda, option-type, java-11

I'm creating a custom Collector but it is failing when using it while compiling.

```
 private static <T> Collector<T, ?, T> getFirstElement() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toList(),
        list -> {
            if (list.size() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            if (list.size() > 1) {
                log.info("There are more than 1 registry");
            }
            return list.get(0);
        }
    );
} 


String myString = "test";
Optional.of(myString)
   .map(myService::getFromDatabase)
   .collect(getFirstElement());
```

myService.getFromDatabase(string) return a list of Items.

I receive an error while compiling

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method collect(java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.lang.Object>)
[ERROR]   location: class java.util.Optional<java.util.List<com.package.Item>>
```

Why am I having this error?

Comment: Did you mean to use `Stream` instead of `Optional`?

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: There's **no issue** with your collector. What is `com.package.Item`? I guess the code you are running differs from the code you've provided. Please post the actual code and specify the return type of `getFromDatabase()` (`Object` ??).

Comment: my code is exactly like this but the type of Item, that is another one with my project, If i set the mouse in the error I have "The method collect(getFirstItem()) is undefined for the type Optional<List<Item>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've said, there are no issues with your collector.

Method `collect()` isn't accessible on the object of type `Optional`. It has methods `map()`, `filter()`, `stream()`, but you can't apply `collect()` on it, don't confuse optional with a stream.

If you need to verify that the string value that has to be passed as an argument into `getFromDatabase()` isn't `null` you can use [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.util.function.Supplier)) (note that `Optional.of()` will throw an exception in the case if the argument is `null`).

Assuming that `getFromDatabase()` returns a list `Item` objects, you can write your code like this:

```
List<Item> items = 
    Stream.of(Objects.requireNonNull(myString, "error message")) // Stream<String>
          .map(myService::getFromDatabase)                       // Stream<List<Item>>
          .flatMap(List::stream)                                 // Stream<Item>
          .collect(getFirstElement());
```

If your intention while you were using `Optional.of()` was to create a result of type `Optinal<List<Item>>` that's not a good idea (*apart from the fact that it would not compile*).

Optional, containing a collection is an *antipattern* because it introduces an unnecessary redundancy. Empty collection serves the same purpose, indicating that there's no data, so there's no need to utilize optional for that.